# Hard Parse on Non-Identical Statements?

Tags: sql, oracle, parsing

Let's say I have this query :

```
SELECT X FROM Y
```

If I run it for the first time then it would do a hard parse.

After that, I run this query :

```
select x from y
```

With just a difference in alphabetical upper and lower case, does it mean they have to do the hard parse all over again?

Thank You.

Comment: Depends on RDBMS. But on SQL Server, yes the statement would need to be recompiled.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat -- I'm running it on Oracle

Comment: I know. That's why I made it a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Check v$sql or v$sqlarea view.

Comment: Well then in the cache, there will be stored 2 statements (the first and second example), am I right?

What if the query is like this : 

`select X from Y`  (note that x and y is uppercase), is that also considered as non-identical?

Comment: Yes, they will be handled as different queries. If there is only difference in one lowercase vs usercase character - it will be treated as different SQL.